# Android twitter connection/authentication intent bad formed?

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter, twitter-oauth

I've been trying to connect to twitter through android for a while.
I'm currently using this api:  http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/forums/forum/topics/13327-Twitter-API-ME-1-8-Now-with-OAuth-support

I used their exemple with my keys and everything connects without problem. So no problem with configuration.
But in my project which has exactly the same code I can't make it work.

I believe its related with the creation of a new Intent (also this is where the eclipse is point the error)

Im trying to use a custom layout but I don't know what do I need to change to make this specific Twitter layout to work. On main activity I have a button with this:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   startActivity(new Intent(this,Twitter.class));
}
```

on twitter class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //this.webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    WebView myWebView = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(myWebView);

    authenticate();             
}

private void authenticate()
{
    WebViewOAuthDialogWrapper page = new WebViewOAuthDialogWrapper(webView);

    page.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
    page.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
    page.setCallbackUrl(CALLBACK_URL);
    page.setOAuthListener(this);

    page.login();
}
```

what requirements/adjustments are needed to make/change to the Twitter activity?

I believe I need to change something in the intent-filter but I don't even understand the work of intents. I've been only making easy layouts.

Note that I also gave internet permissions already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i was making 2 mistakes.

First i was trying to use "webView" variable in WebViewOAuthDialogWrapper instead
"myWebView" so it wasn't initialized...

Second looks like i forgot to put the order of which the external libraries were loaded....
So be sure to put external libraries on top in eclipse project.

Lost about 2 days with these problems... oh well